# Query unrendered components

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

What is the best way to query unrendered components? I tried to query them as always using `.query( '[group=abc]' )`.

However this time, the components, having each `group: abc`, are not yet rendered, since they are used in an editable grid (first click it).

What I am trying to do is:

- get data via Ajax for comboboxes
- create an unknown number of comboboxes
- put that Ajax data into each combobox
- Problem: I want that boxes to be filled with the data on Ajax success
- loading the data on Ajax success answer fails since I am missing a method to get my comboboxes via the property `group=abc`
- loading the data on combobox creation fails too, since the Ajax success answer is not yet back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to use `ComponentQuery` for unrendered components.  You best bet is probably your last list item: Load the data into the combo stores when the combos are created.  The key will be to mask the action that creates the combos (is this a grid row editor or something like that?) until the Ajax call is complete.

```
myComponent.setLoading(true);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    //your request info here
    success: function() {
        //now unmask your component, allowing your combos to be created:
        myComponent.setLoading(false);
        //do other stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not try your solution. I am now using a polling solution with an array holding the comboboxes.